# Detecting embeded video format

Tags: shortcode, embed

I need to get the video format from the shortcode. Example if i set my post meta "_video_format_embed" with `[video src="https://url.domain/myvideo.mp4" /]` .

how to get the video format of my shortcode?

```
$video_embeded = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_video_format_embed');
$video_format = '???'; // please help
if('mp4' === $video_format){
 //some code
}
```

Comment: what do you get in return, when you place `echo '<pre>', print_r( $video_embeded ), '</pre>';` right after your first line?

Comment: it will show the video player. I didn't get any code in there if I dump or echo in a pre tag, it will show the video player.

Comment: ok. so it returns the video code. bueno. please add the following to your functions.php and report back: `function so327822_wp_video_shortcode($output, $atts, $video, $post_id, $library) {
 echo '<pre>', print_r($atts), '</pre>';
 echo '<pre>', print_r($video), '</pre>';
 echo '<pre>', print_r($library), '</pre>';
}
add_filter('wp_video_shortcode', 'so327822_wp_video_shortcode', 10, 5);` its a filter, that hooks into the wordpress video shortcode function..

Comment: it show an Array `<pre>Array
(
    [src] => http://domain/video.mp4
    [poster] => 
    [loop] => 
    [autoplay] => 
    [preload] => metadata
    [width] => 640
    [height] => 360
    [class] => wp-video-shortcode
    [mp4] => 
    [m4v] => 
    [webm] => 
    [ogv] => 
    [flv] => 
)
1</pre>
<pre>1</pre>
<pre>mediaelement1</pre>`

Comment: OK. one step further.. please replace this one with the previous code: `function so327822_wp_video_shortcode($output, $atts) { $video_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $atts['src'] ); $video_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $video_id ); echo '<pre>' . print_r($video_meta, true) . '</pre>';} add_filter('wp_video_shortcode', 'so327822_wp_video_shortcode', 10, 2);` and return back, i'm almost certain, that it includes the mime_type..

Comment: Hi , It shows an array again.
here the array  : `Array
(
    [bitrate] => 1478916
    [filesize] => 2038352
    [mime_type] => video/quicktime
    [length] => 11
    [length_formatted] => 0:11
    [width] => 640
    [height] => 360
    [fileformat] => mp4
    [dataformat] => quicktime
    [created_timestamp] => 1371138809
)`. 

Now, How to get the file format without break the video? Thanks you

Comment: ok. mime_type and fileformat, all in there.. and what does `$video_embeded = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_video_format_embed');` return? the ID of the video, or what? can you tell me that, too. then we are done with this <3

Comment: the return can be **embed code** or **URL** . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you place your video inside a shortcode and then you can run a filter on that shortcode function. works like this (to be placed inside functions.php or some custom plugin):

```
function so327822_wp_video_shortcode($output, $atts) {
    //get video ID by src
    $video_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $atts['src'] );
    //get video meta
    $video_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $video_id );
    //uncomment next line, to view all meta
    //echo '<pre>' . print_r($video_meta, true) . '</pre>';

    if ( $video_meta['fileformat'] === 'mp4' ) {
        //mess with $output here, if we have mp4
    }

    //return 
    return $output;
}
add_filter('wp_video_shortcode', 'so327822_wp_video_shortcode', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you honk31.  I will experiment with the code above.